# Send more than one response to the same client

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

I want to send more than one response to the same client.
I'm using Web Forms, when the user clicks the button, it wraps a "postback" to the server. The server generates a CSV file, and returns a Response with "ContentType: text / csv" to the client, so the browser downloads the file.

I wanted to get the user to download the file, and then update the page's HTML. This all in the same requisition.

Comment: The only way is to do a PostBack first, and then open a link to the page that is generating a CSV with a javascript/jQuery trigger.

Comment: @VDWWD Well thats absolutely a way, but not the only way. You can for example do the whole thing async using a separate file generator service via ajax.

Comment: you can only have one response per HTTP request. So if you want to do multiple different things, you need more than one request.

Comment: I use a third party component, a Telerik RadGrid, inside the server the grid has the method "ExportToCsv ()", there he takes care of the whole process.